# Automatically add id of current page to href

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a link below as it is found in a particular WordPress plugin:

```
<a href='".home_url("?p=7&action=get_marks&id=$select_data2->id")."' ></a>
```

I want to auto detect page_id when I click on it to reload the same page, like:

```
 <a href='".home_url("?p=get_id&action=get_marks&id=$select_data2->id")."'></a>
```

I don't want to write page id every time I create new page after putting shortcode in.

Comment: I fixed grammar and spelling, mostly. Make sure your code has the right syntax; it looks like there are wrapping double quotes missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about server side

```
echo '<a href=".home_url("?p='.$id.'&action=get_marks&id=$select_data2->id")."></a> '
```

where $id is a variable that has the id

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered JavaScript on the client side?

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.reload();"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help 
i tried several method until i found the solution 
 here the code

```
global $post;
echo '<a href='".home_url("?p=$post->ID&action=get_marks&id=$select_data2->id")."'>';
```

where $post->ID is a variable that has the page id

thanks @user74670 you give me inspiration to solve problem